# ViewController и CollectionView или как передать данные по новой

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Имеем CollectionView -> ViewController. В VС имеем кнопку, которая выводит картинку которую сохранил через NSUserDefaults (как правильный ответ).
Само собой имеем что в VC картинка сохраненная в память будет выскакивать в каждой нажатой ячейке :
так как находится в ViewDidLoad()

```
let imgData1 = defaults.objectForKey("image2") as? NSData
    if imgData1 != nil {
        StarTextField.hidden = false
        TextFieldButton.hidden = true
        let image = UIImage(data: imgData1!)
        print("Star is Here")
    } else {
        print("Star not Here")
    }
```

Ну и наконец сам Вопрос) Как сделать чтоб не в каждой ячейке была сохраненная картинка а там где была пройдена проверка ?

---

Вопрос решен, почти))) Путем добавление доп. параметра в словарь со значением Bool и его вставке к сравнению. Сейчас Думаю как изменить параметр Bool в словаре.

Comment: Какая проверка? Картинка в `ViewController` или в `CollectionView`?

Comment: картинка в ViewController (StarTextField) при открытии любой ячейки она уже в памяти и условие if отрабатывает  сразу на всех ячейках как только в ячейке прошла проверка : короч гляди : if TextField1.text == navigationItem.title {          дальше сохраняем картинку как условие правельное let imgData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(StarTextField.image!)
            defaults.setObject(imgData1, forKey: "image2")  и теперь получается что так как условие 1 раз отработало и картинка в памяти записалась то условие в ViewDidLoad постоянно будет отрабатывать. а мне необходимо чтоб при каждой новой ячейки

Comment: условие if TextField1.text == navigationItem.title по новой отрабатывало, при каждой новой ячейки а на старых ячейках условие в ViewDidLoad оставалось True. Есть мысля добавить в Массив параметр типа Bool (false, True) и добавить в сравнении еще 1 параметр с записью. Но из за недостатка опыта проблемотично придумать как это все соорудить ))